# Instantiate entity in controller Spring MVC, good pratice?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, model-view-controller

I wanted to know if calling an entity in a controller a good developpement habit or not.

Example :

**Entity :**

```
@Entity
public class Project {

@Id
private Long id;
private String name;
private String type;
private boolean done = false;
//Getters & Setters
}
```

**Controller**

```
@Controller
public class ProjectController {

@RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String addProject (Model model) {

model.addAttribute("entity", new Project());
return "addProject";
}
}
```

Any other suggestion is welcome.

Comment: What do you mean about "calling an entity"?

Comment: I maent initiating an instance of an entity `new ()`.

Comment: Yes it's ok. But if in other method you would also return that object, then method with @ModelAttribute annotation is better.